# Is custom authorizer really an optimal way to secure AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My use case is a Lambda function behind API Gateway. I use API as a proxy with /{proxy+} path and method ANY. I want to secure my Lambda function so, that only authorized users can execute it and perform only allowed actions using this function. I know, that the way to go is to create custom authorizer. But I think this approach is pretty ineffective.

Two cons:

1. Every time my API is used, two Lambda functions will be executed instead of one: authorizer and main Lambda . Both Lambdas in my case will connect to database. Authorizer - to verify user and decide what policy to return. Main Lambda - to perform its task. It will cost extra money and reduce the speed of my app.
2. Authorizer can only decide, whether user is allowed to execute my function or not. It cannot decide whether user is allowed to perform some specific action by the Lambda function. So my access logic will be splitted: part of it will be in authorizer and another part, more specific, in my Lambda. Not very good.

Isn't it better not to use custom authorizer in my case and just pass all requests to my main Lambda, which will decide whether user is authorized or not? In the latter it will just send response with code 401 (Unauthorized).

I understand that custom authorizer is a more universal approach, because it allows to protect all types of API integrations besides Lambda (HTTP, Mock, etc.), but in my case it is Lambda function.

Comment: The main intended way to authorize external lambda calls is using api gateway.. (with API key or client cert). Using custom authorizer is IMHO for fine grained / custom authorization. Separate lambda is good for concern separation (not mixing security with business logic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using AWS Custom authorizer function to authorize the users, it provides a TTL value where you can instruct the function to cache the [results](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-custom-authorizer-output.html) for a specific time period for a given user token.

Answering to your 1st point, this way the logic in custom authorizer does not run for each invocation, rather it caches and returns the API Gateway policy and context variables you return from the custom authorizer, within the TTL.

Regarding your 2nd point, custom authorizer can basically decide which actions an user can perform if you are able to map the allowed user actions to API Gateway paths.  This is implemented using [API Gateway Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-create-and-manage-api.html#api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies).

E.g: You can verify whether the user is an administrator inside the custom authorizer and generate an API Gateway policy allowing permission to perform **.../users/create (POST)** action on API Gateway and return it from custom authorizer.

In addition, it is also a good practice to query the frequently used user and tenant attributes in custom authorizer and return in the context variable, so that it does not require to query them always, inside endpoint Lambda function.

Comment: Really informative, thank you.
1. Caching reduces this point greatly, but there is a drawback. Revoked access rights won't be revoked immidiately.
2. In my case I use one API proxy endpoint and one lambda function. My lambda routes requests (it analizes event path and other parameters). So I cannot use policy to give permissions to perform specific actions. In my case it will be just "yes" or "no" about executing single lambda function.

But anyway, probably this is the answer since it is pouring light on the topic.

Comment: Moreover I am using sam-local and custom authorizers are still not implemented in sam-local, so I think I'll go without custom authorizer.

Comment: @ashan What is the main advantage of using custom authorizer vs the API Key?Also is it possible to implement quota based throttling with custom authorizer (similar to key based quota)?

Comment: @himanshu219 API Key is for mainly used for usage control (e.g; rate limiting) and monitoring (e.g; usage reports, billing). Although it could be used for B2B auth scenarios it is not recommended. On the other hand, custom authorizer could support both B2B and B2C auth scenarios as well as work in conjunction with API keys.

Comment: @ashan  why it is not recommended is it because of security?

Comment: Yes. This is because of security. Anyway, when it comes to user authentication, API Keys doesn't work at all.